# How to massively remove many users on Windows Small Business Server 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-sbs

I want to massively remove all users from my Windows Small Business Server 2003 installation except `Administrator` and `Guest`. They are too many to remove them one-by-one. It takes a lot of time.

Is there a way to remove these users massively?

Comment: There are other built-in accounts that you want to keep too.

Comment: Yes. You are right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you go to your Active Directory Users and Computers console (under Administrative Tools), you should be able to select multiple users inside a single OU and delete them all at once:

[image]

This should make it a lot quicker.

(that screenshot was taken on an SBS2011 machine, but it's pretty much the same on 2003).

Comment: Thanks that worked. I am really wondering why it is impossible to select many users and act on all of them from the System Management / Users form. Anyway. Thanks again.

Comment: @p.matsinopoulos - because the SBS console is designed for really anyone without any technical knowledge to work with, so I'm guessing they made it work for lowest common denominator and nothing else. Although I think in later versions you can select multiple users from the SBS console.